# How to acquire FileLock without resource warning?

Tags: file, java-8, path, file-locking

I have the below code:

```
try {
    final Path lock = Files.write(PATH_TO_FILE_IN_A_CONSTANT, "Executing Job", StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

    final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(lock.toFile(), "r");
    FileLock fl = new FileInputStream(raf.getFD()).getChannel().lock(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, true);
} catch (final IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error while trying to write file. ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), e);

    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(-1);
}
```

The problem is that since I don't close [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), both [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)`'s` objects I get a warning that I'm not closing objects and this may lead to resource leaks. If I do close this objects the file looses the lock granted. I need the file locked while the job is being executed, and after that I just delete it.

I can use [SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) `"resource"`annotation, but instead of doing this I tried to research for a solution, but unfortunatelly I did not get any success.

Is there anyway to acquire the lock and not get this warning?

Comment: So you are locking the file here ? And then ? Where are you using the file & when are you releasing the lock ? Compiler warnings are build for a reason, thumb rule, open a resource, lock it, use/read it, and close it once done. And these are sequence of tasks you perform with any allocated resource as one single unit of work. If compiler see cycle is not completing, it's righly complaining for resource leak.

Comment: @AmithKumar, as I said, I need the file locked the whole time the batch is being executed, once the job is done I added the lock release inside a shutdownHook.

Comment: Why are you going this detour to open a `FileChannel`? Even if you don't use [`FileChannel.open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) to open the channel directly, `RandomAccessFile` has a `getChannel()` method, on the other hand, you can open a `FileInputStream` without opening a `RandomAccessFile` first. So there never was a reason to open three resources to get to the lock. And if you use `FileChannel.open`, you only have to keep and close the channel.

Comment: And you *have to keep* the `FileChannel` and close it at the right time, as when you don’t do it, the garbage collector may do it at an entirely unpredictable point of time.

Comment: @AmithKumar, actually using `FileChannel.open` didn't give me the lock, however with `RandomAccessFile` it was succesfull. I was not aware of the `'getChannel` method in `RandomAccessFile`. Thanks! Any leads on why `FileChannel.open`won't work?

Comment: @Holger, question your way. I got mistakenly addressed.

Comment: Without further context, I can only guess. You have to specify `StandardOpenOption.READ` when opening the channel, to acquire a shared lock, and you need both, `READ` and `StandardOpenOption.WRITE`, to be able to acquire an exclusive lock. The spec says that attempts to acquire a shared lock are automatically converted to exclusive lock attempts, if shared is not supported, but I doubt that this is the case. Mind to not create the `RandomAccessFile` before opening the channel via `FileChannel.open`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can achieve file lock without IO operation, and IO operation needs sure closure otherwise compiler will complain. You will have to tweak your approach to achieve the solution:

```
public class FileLockMaster {
    //easy way to use ThreadLocal, if the batch threads are child to this thread, set release in batch shutdownHook
    InheritableThreadLocal<Lock> lock = new InheritableThreadLocal<>(); 
    //or you can create a instance or static variable here to be set in child batch threads in shutdownHook,
    //depending on batch threads will have access to instance or not respectively


    public void acquireFileLock(){
        Path PATH_TO_FILE_IN_A_CONSTANT = null;
        byte[] Executing_Job = null;
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        FileLock fl = null;
        FileInputStream fStream = null;
        //or you can use try with resources with while() loop inside try block
        try {
            final Path lock = Files.write(PATH_TO_FILE_IN_A_CONSTANT, Executing_Job, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(lock.toFile(), "r");
            fStream = new FileInputStream(raf.getFD()); 
            fl = fStream.getChannel().lock(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, true);

            /**
             * create batch threads here or outside to complete the job
             */

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while trying to write file. ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(-1);
        } finally{
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (this.lock.get().release) {
                        raf.close();
                        fStream.close();
                        fl.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                //ignore
            }
    }
}

class Lock{
    boolean release;
}
```